# heroku migration of apps from public space to private space

Tags: heroku

We are moving bunch of our apps from public space to private space. We have created all the scripts to do the migration but facing a challenge to move the db records for one of the app from public space db to private space db. Has anyone gone through this process?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to say this but currently this is not possible with a single click. You have to create a new app inside a private space, migrate all the config vars, deploy your changes, and then if you want you can delete your public space app.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by creating a follower of your database in Private spaces. It is possible to create followers of Common runtime databases in Private spaces. Below are the steps you can follow:

```
$ heroku pg:info --app common-runtime-sushi
=== DATABASE_URL, HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_GREEN_URL
Plan:        Standard 0
Status:      available
Add-on:      looking-simply-2449
...

$ heroku addons:create heroku-postgresql:private-4 --follow looking-simply-2449 -a private-spaces-sushi
Adding heroku-postgresql:private-4 to sushi... done, v71 ($1500/mo)
Attached as HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_PURPLE
Follower will become available for read-only queries when up-to-date
```

Eventually promote the follower as primary in your new Private spaces app. You can find the steps involved here:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/migrating-heroku-postgres-databases-to-private-spaces